# Recent Restrictions on Limits

Tags: apex

Did Salesforce recently enforce any new restrictions on DML on Lists ?.

My colleague told me to exercise caution while  using via lists citing the above.

I searched online and I am not able to get any info.

Can someone guide me as to where to find out official info regarding those new restrictions ?

Comment: The question is a little bit too vague as to answer it properly. Your best information are the release notes, which would contain such information: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to date spec is in [Understanding Execution Governors and Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) chapter of Force.com documentation. In context of your question, note that you are limited not by size of list but by heap size and amount of records that DML could consume. It's not new. I did not notice any new change in release notes for last two editions connected with mentioned issue. I might be wrong but some time ago (in 2009 I think) there was a limit for lists but they removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Open any Debug Log and check at the Bottom you can see all Governor Limits.
SetUp -->  Logs --> Debug Logs--> View.

Number of SOQL queries:  100
  Number of query rows:  50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 20
  Number of DML statements: 150
  Number of DML rows:  10000
  Maximum CPU time:  10000
  Maximum heap size:  6000000
  Number of callouts: 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 10
  Number of future calls:  10
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls:  10

Hope this information helps you.

Thanks,
Raviteja